# Ruby: Understanding Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write a script that will match all words in a string and will strip all non words (IE: . [dot], ampersands, colons, etc) out and will replace them with a hyphen.

Example String:
`L. L. Cool J & Sons: The Cool Kats`

Example Output:
`L-L-Cool-J-Sons-The-Cool-Kats`

Here is some code I am working with:

```
str = "L. L. Cool J & Sons: The Cool Kats"
str.scan(/\w+/)
```

Thanks for all the help! I am still pretty new to regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I just noticed that the two calls can be expressed as one:

```
str.gsub(/\W+/, '-')
=> "L-L-Cool-J-Sons-The-Cool-Kats"
```

...which results to the same as Narendra's answer or my original answer:

```
# 1st gsub: replace all non-words with hyphens
# 2nd gsub: replace multiple hyphens with a single one
str.gsub(/\W/,'-').gsub(/-+/, '-')
=> "L-L-Cool-J-Sons-The-Cool-Kats"
```

Answer (score 2):

In a single line, find all bits of text that aren't "word characters" and replace with a dash:

```
str.gsub(/\W+/, '-')
```

Note that "word characters" includes numbers and underscores. To just allow letters you could use the following:

```
str.gsub(/[^A-Za-z]+/, '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\W` for non word characters. It should do your job. `\w` stands for word characters. I don't work much with ruby but it should look something like this 
`result = subject.gsub(/\W+/, '-')` .

Answer (score 0):

```
str.gsub(/\W/, '-')          #=> replaces all non-words with space
                             # OR
str.gsub(/[^A-Za-z\s]/, ' ') #=> replace all non letters/spaces with space
str.gsub(/\s+/, '-')         #=> replaces all groups of spaces to hypens
```

**Input:**

`L. L. Cool J & Sons: The Cool Kats`

**Output:**

`L-L-Cool-J-Sons-The-Cool-Kats`